# How to find determinant of 4d GPU array

Tags: matlab

I'm new to using the GPU in MATLAB, I've got 4d array, let's call that A, where `size(A) = [100, 200, 3, 3]`. I want to do something like:

```
for i = 1:size(A, 1)
    for j = 1:size(A, 2)
        B(i, j) = det(squeeze(A(i,j,:,:)));
    end
end
```

If `A` is already a `gpuArray`, how can I implement this without the use of for loops? I've tried both pagefun and arrayfun, but they both don't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have a choice but to loop.  `det` works only on square 2D matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Worked around it by explicitly defining the determinant function. That is

```
function DET = my3x3det(a11, a12, a13, a21, a22, a23, a31, a32, a33)
    DET = a11.*(a22.*a33 - a23.*a32) - ...
          a12.*(a21.*a33 - a23.*a31) + ...
          a13.*(a21.*a32 - a22.*a31);
end
```

Then instead of the for-loop, `B` can be obtained using `arrayfun`

```
B = arrayfun(@my3x3det, A(:,:,1,1), A(:,:,1,2), A(:,:,1,3), ...
                        A(:,:,2,1), A(:,:,2,2), A(:,:,2,3), ...
                        A(:,:,3,1), A(:,:,3,2), A(:,:,3,3));
```

Which works out to be faster than solving for the same thing in a for-loop. It's a little cumbersome, but it works for this case where specifically a 3x3 determinant is needed.